# Bug: Mesh file path in URDF. Cannot locate resource file://

Tags: urdf, mesh, ogre, solidworks, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi 
I've saved a SolidWorks file as an ASCII .STL, opened it in MeshLab and re-saved as a Binary .STL

When I try to test it using the file:// descriptor in a URDF file I'm getting some errors:

XML code is:

```
[ERROR] [1342609158.212504927]: Error retrieving file [file://home/username/path/path/filename.stl]: Couldn't open file /username/path/path/filename.stl
[ERROR] [1342609158.213501127]: Could not load model 'file://home/username/path/path/filename.stl' for link 'Mounting_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource file://home/username/path/path/filename.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-visualization-common-1.8.4/debian/ros-fuerte-visualization-common/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 753)
```

** Notice that in the error it looks like it may be truncating the word 'home' and trying to load "/username/path/path/filename.stl".

When I change the path to:

the mesh loads correctly.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39116/bug:-mesh-file-path-in-urdf.--cannot-locate-resource-file:///) by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1103 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-18**:
So what exactly is your question? For bug reports, it's best to file a ticket at the corresponding trac: https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/Trac

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2012-07-18**:
Ok, will do that.  Originally this was a question, then I edited it when I found a solution  :-)

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2012-07-24**:
https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/Trac/ticket/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you're looking for a file using file:// like http:// usually you need 3 slashes to tell it that it's a absolute url.  try "file:///home/username/path/path/filename.stl" if you don't the first argument after the slashes is considered the hostname.

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlopen('file:///tmp/foo')
<addinfourl at 17115976 whose fp = <open file '/tmp/foo', mode 'rb' at 0x7f449c12aae0>>
>>> urllib.urlopen('file://tmp/foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 205, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 465, in open_file
    return self.open_ftp(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 522, in open_ftp
    host = socket.gethostbyname(host)
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on 2018-10-10**:
This syntax worked better for me "file:///$(find package_name)/path/to/file". This will likely work for different machines.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use the [Resource_retriever](http://www.ros.org/wiki/resource_retriever/Tutorials/Retrieving%20Files) syntax which is more platform independent.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2012-07-24**:
@David Lu: Sorry my post above had a copy-paste error. I've edited it now.

file:// is part of resource_retriever (http://www.ros.org/wiki/resource_retriever)

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-09**:
What @David Lu probably means is that you should use 'package://name of your package/path/to/file' instead of putting absolute paths that work only on your machine.

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-01-10**:
I use package:// instead of file, however still fail. the files were exported from sw_urdf_exporter